# Git, backup working copy, Visual Studio 2010

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010

Git does not have a way to backup a working copy.  (You can use git commit, but that pollutes your repo with backups.)  So I use git diff, but it has an issue with Visual Studio 2010 (VS).  Sometimes, VS saves C# files as UTF-8, sometimes UTF-16LE.  When VS switches a file from one to the other, the git patch file says, "Binary files a/path1/file1.cs and b/path1/file1.cs differ," and git apply cannot restore from the patch file.  What's the easiest solution?

Comment: Git isn't a backup tool. What's wrong with whatever you use for regular system backups?

Comment: I never said Git was a backup tool.  Many people use git commit/push to backup their working copy changes.  Regular system backups backup too much stuff.  I only want to backup the changes to my working copy because I do it often.  "Save early, save often."

Comment: My point is that you're trying to use Git for something it isn't meant to do. If you want to do backups, use a backup tool. Most of them are very configurable; there's nothing forcing you to "backup too much stuff".

Comment: I never said the solution had to be a feature of Git.  There are no backup tools that will backup only the uncommitted changed and added files in a Git working copy.  So I developed a tool to do it and put it here: https://github.com/user7251/repo1/tree/master/BackupGitWorkingCopy

Comment: You recommended that I configure a backup tool.  What backup tool can I easily configure to backup only the uncommitted changed and added files in a Git working copy?

Comment: I would likely just back up the whole project directory (ignoring `.git/` if you really want to, but it's probably a good idea to include it). Unless you've got some weird requirements that you haven't explained this is a good and simple solution. If you're worried about backing up the same data each time you could use a differential or incremental backup.

Comment: A differential or incremental backup is a good solution, but BackupGitWorkingCopy is more efficient because it doesn't backup files that I have in synch on my remote Git repo.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a solution, BackupGitWorkingCopy at https://github.com/user7251/repo1/tree/master/BackupGitWorkingCopy

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to backup the changed/new/untracked files somewhere outside the repo, you can use:

```
git status -s | awk '{print $2}' | xargs tar -czf /root/git_backup.tar.gz
```